# Format cross tabs in a pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have this query that pivots race grouped by age

```
        create table test4(city nvarchar(10), race nvarchar(30), sex nvarchar(10), age int)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'African-American', 'male', 21)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Asian', 'female', 22)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Caucasian', 'male', 23)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Hispanic', 'female', 24)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'African-American', 'Unknown', 25)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Asian', 'male', 26)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Caucasian', 'female', 27)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Hispanic', 'Unknown', 28)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Asian', 'male', 29)
        insert into test4 values ('Austin',  'Caucasian', 'female', 31)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Hispanic', 'Unknown', 32)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'African-American', 'male', 33)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Asian', 'female', 34)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Caucasian', 'Unknown', 35)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Hispanic', 'male', 500)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'African-American', 'female', 36)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Asian', 'Unknown', 37)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Caucasian', 'male', 38)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'Hispanic', 'female', 39)
        insert into test4 values ('Dallas',  'African-American', 'Unknown', 41)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Asian', 'male', 42)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Caucasian', 'female', 43)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Hispanic', 'Unknown', 44)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'African-American', 'male', 45)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Asian', 'female', 46)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Caucasian', 'Unknown', 47)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Hispanic', 'male', 48)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'African-American', 'female', 49)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Asian', 'Unknown', 51)
        insert into test4 values ('Houston',  'Caucasian', 'male', 52);

        WITH T AS (
        SELECT 
              A.city as city, A.sex as sex,  
              CASE
                    WHEN A.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30_' + race
                    WHEN A.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40_' + race
                    WHEN A.age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50_' + race
               END AS age_range_race
       FROM test4 AS A
       )
       SELECT  *
       FROM T
       PIVOT( COUNT(age_range_race) FOR age_range_race
           IN(
              [20-30_African-American], 
              [20-30_Asian], 
              [20-30_Caucasian], 
              [20-30_Hispanic],
              [31-40_African-American], 
              [31-40_Asian], 
              [31-40_Caucasian], 
              [31-40_Hispanic],
              [41-50_African-American], 
              [41-50_Asian], 
              [41-50_Caucasian], 
              [41-50_Hispanic]
             )
        ) AS P
```

and when I run it I get this

[image: 1]

but what I need is this, without the age ranges.

[image: 1]

I am going to be putting the pivot in a Radgrid with a custom header that will display the age ranges so they will not be needed in the column headers.  Is this possible? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure whether you want the age ranges collapsed into a single column, or if you want the same column names repeated in your query.  If you want them collapsed:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0ca0/3

```
    WITH T AS (
    SELECT 
          A.city as city, A.sex as sex,  
          CASE
                WHEN A.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30_' + race
                WHEN A.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40_' + race
                WHEN A.age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50_' + race
           END AS age_range_race
   FROM test4 AS A
   )
   SELECT  
      P.city,
      P.sex,
      [20-30_African-American] + [31-40_African-American] + [41-50_African-American] as [African-American],

      [20-30_Asian] + [31-40_Asian] + [41-50_Asian] as [Asian],

      [20-30_Caucasian] + [31-40_Caucasian] + [41-50_Caucasian] as [Caucasian],

      [20-30_Hispanic] + [31-40_Hispanic] + [41-50_Hispanic] as [Hispanic]
   FROM T
   PIVOT( COUNT(age_range_race) FOR age_range_race
       IN(
          [20-30_African-American], 
          [20-30_Asian], 
          [20-30_Caucasian], 
          [20-30_Hispanic],
          [31-40_African-American], 
          [31-40_Asian], 
          [31-40_Caucasian], 
          [31-40_Hispanic],
          [41-50_African-American], 
          [41-50_Asian], 
          [41-50_Caucasian], 
          [41-50_Hispanic]
         )
    ) AS P
```

If you really want the same columns names returned multiple times, I think you're really asking for a headache.  This is the closest I can offer (although it isn't that great of a solution, since it doesn't do much beyond your base setup):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0ca0/5

```
    WITH T AS (
    SELECT 
          A.city as city, A.sex as sex,  
          CASE
                WHEN A.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30_' + race
                WHEN A.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40_' + race
                WHEN A.age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50_' + race
           END AS age_range_race
   FROM test4 AS A
   )
   SELECT  
      P.city,
      P.sex,
          [20-30_African-American] as [African-American1], 
          [20-30_Asian] as [Asian1], 
          [20-30_Caucasian] as [Caucasian1], 
          [20-30_Hispanic] as [Hispanic1],
          [31-40_African-American] as [African-American2], 
          [31-40_Asian] as [Asian2], 
          [31-40_Caucasian] as [Caucasian2], 
          [31-40_Hispanic] as [Hispanic2],
          [41-50_African-American] as [African-American3], 
          [41-50_Asian] as [Asian3], 
          [41-50_Caucasian] as [Caucasian3], 
          [41-50_Hispanic] as [Hispanic3]

   FROM T
   PIVOT( COUNT(age_range_race) FOR age_range_race
       IN(
          [20-30_African-American], 
          [20-30_Asian], 
          [20-30_Caucasian], 
          [20-30_Hispanic],
          [31-40_African-American], 
          [31-40_Asian], 
          [31-40_Caucasian], 
          [31-40_Hispanic],
          [41-50_African-American], 
          [41-50_Asian], 
          [41-50_Caucasian], 
          [41-50_Hispanic]
         )
    ) AS P
```

Comment: BTW - I'm the developer of sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I appreciate your help, but I really need the same column names returned multiple times, if possible.

Comment: Well, I assume then you must plan on disambiguating the columns by their position in the result set rather than their name.  In that case - just remove the trailing numbers from the column aliases in my second example and that should be what you want.